# Sitecore 8 XP ContentSearch: Exclude path from Indexing

Tags: indexing, solr, sitecore, sitecore8, commerce

I'm having trouble with Sitecore Indexing of the general indexes "sitecore_master_index", "sitecore_web_index", which take forever because the crawler/indexer checks all items in the database.

I imported thousands of products with a whole lot of specifications and literally have hundreds of thousands of items in the product repository.

If I could exclude the path from indexing it wouldn't have to check a million items for template exclusion.

FOLLOWUP

I implemented a custom-crawler that excludes a list of paths from being indexed:

```xml
<index id="sitecore_web_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
  <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
  <param desc="core">sitecore_web_index</param>
  <param desc="rebuildcore">sitecore_web_index_sec</param>
  <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
  <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration" />
  <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
    <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
  </strategies>
  <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
    <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.Crawler.ExcludePathsItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities">
      <Database>web</Database>
      <Root>/sitecore</Root>
      <ExcludeItemsList hint="list">
        <ProductRepository>/sitecore/content/Product Repository</ProductRepository>
      </ExcludeItemsList>
    </crawler>
  </locations>
</index>
```

In addition I activated SwitchOnSolrRebuildIndex as it's awesome ootb functionality, cheers SC.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;

namespace Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.Crawler
{
  public class ExcludePathsItemCrawler : SitecoreItemCrawler
  {
    private readonly List<string> excludeItemsList = new List<string>();
    public List<string> ExcludeItemsList
    {
      get
      {
        return excludeItemsList;
      }
    }

    protected override bool IsExcludedFromIndex(SitecoreIndexableItem indexable, bool checkLocation = false)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull(indexable, "item");
      if (ExcludeItemsList.Any(path => indexable.AbsolutePath.StartsWith(path)))
      {
        return true;
      }
      return base.IsExcludedFromIndex(indexable, checkLocation);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: worth possibly setting the indexable.AbsolutePath and path values ToLower to prevent casing issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `SitecoreItemCrawler` class which is used by the index you want to change:

```xml
<locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
  <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <Database>master</Database>
    <Root>/sitecore</Root>
  </crawler>
</locations>
```

You can then add your own parameters, e.g. `ExcludeTree` or even a list of `ExcludedBranches`.

And in the implementation of the class just override method

```cs
public override bool IsExcludedFromIndex(IIndexable indexable)
```

and check whether it is under excluded node.

Comment: I tried that but sadly to no effect.

16664 14:36:26 WARN  IndexCustodian. FullRebuild triggered on index sitecore_master_index.

14904 14:36:51 INFO  Crawler [sitecore_master_index]: Processed 1000 items

...

14904 14:46:37 INFO  Crawler [sitecore_master_index]: Processed 237000 items

...


It still checks every single Item.

Comment: It does. There is no way of avoiding that. Sitecore checks every item during Full Index Rebuild. But with this, you don't have to check excluded templates which is much more CPU consuming than checking whether item is descendant of another.

Comment: In the end I did it, in respective re-indexing the whole index should not happen too often, cause items should be indexed on publish and that coupled with an AutoPublish in workflow should do the trick.
thxalot Marek

Answer (score 0):

When importing large amounts of data you should try disabling the indexing of data temporarily otherwise you'll run into issues with a crawler that can't keep up.

There's a great post here on disabling the index while importing data - it's for Lucene but I'm sure you can do the same with Solr,

http://intothecore.cassidy.dk/2010/09/disabling-lucene-indexes.html

Another option could be to store your products in a separate Sitecore database rather than in the master db.

Another post from into the core:

http://intothecore.cassidy.dk/2009/05/working-with-multiple-content-databases.html

Comment: I am already disabling the relevant indexes during import. Thx anyway!
Maybe I rly have to go for the separate DB  option...

Comment: One other thing - you could adjust the FullRebuildItemCountThreshold to stop a a full rebuild of the index https://dev.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/index_update_strategies

Comment: Also you could make sure that the products are stored in the tree where the crawler can't get to them . The crawler has a root setting - if you were to move the products outside this the crawler would not check them. If you wanted to index the products separately you could then create a IndexConfiguration for that.